Validator Payout Issue After Polkadot v1.4.0 Upgrade: `AlreadyClaimed` Error
After upgrading my chain to Polkadot v1.4.0, one of my validators has started reporting a strange issue related to payouts:
Validator Issue:
•   The validator still shows up as needing to be paid out in the payouts section.
•   When we manually trigger the payout using staking.payoutStakers, it throws the error AlreadyClaimed.
•   On the targets tab, the validator does not appear under recently claimed.
Steps Taken So Far:

Attempted to manually process the payout using staking.payoutStakers.
Result: AlreadyClaimed.

Verified reward points and staking details for the validator:
•   Validator actively participated in the specified era, with reward points and stake details consistent with expectations.

Checked for pending payouts:
•   Validator is still showing as needing a payout.


Observations:
•   This issue started immediately after upgrading the chain to Polkadot v1.4.0.
•   I suspect this might be related to either a change in payout logic introduced in the new version or a UI-related issue with PolkadotJS Apps.
Any guidance or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
Recent Observation:
I tested this for a specific validator and era:
1.  Checked the validator’s free balance before triggering the payout.

2.  Manually triggered staking.payoutStakers for the specified era.

3.  Checked the validator’s free balance again after the payout.

The difference matched the expected reward amount, confirming that the payout was processed successfully on-chain.
•   Despite the rewards being correctly credited to the validator’s account, the validator still does not appear under “recently claimed” on the targets tab of PolkadotJS Apps.
•   This strongly suggests the problem may be with the PolkadotJS UI rather than the chain logic.
I’m continuing to debug this issue and would appreciate any insights or recommendations from the community!
